# Jenkins - Change property files of the checked out files of the workspace before build

Tags: ant, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins version 1.577 for a project. I want to modify some property file values (eg. `JAVA_HOME`, `TOMCAT_HOME`) after the project is checked out to workspace, but before the build.

How to do that through Jenkins?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can run the script which changes JAVA_HOME, TOMCAT_HOME etc. in your checked-out file(s) in the build step itself. Just mention it in the same shell before the line where build script is getting called.

Alternatively, you can simply set JAVA_HOME, TOMCAT_HOME within the `same shell` just before you're calling the build script. Refer snapshot below:

[image]

By the way, if all you need is to change JAVA_HOME, TOMCAT_HOME etc. for the build, then you can simply configure them in Global config page (screenshot below):

[image]

Once Global configuration is done, just go to your job's configuration page and select the desired version from the drop-down list. Refer the screenshot below:

[image]

This last approach also provides you the flexibility to use *different versions* of the same program (JAVA, for instance) in different jobs as per your need. Needless to say, it also reduces chances of error while configuring various jobs' configuration while setting these parameters.

You should also check [EnvInject Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin). In the link, search for "*Inject variables after a SCM checkout*"

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. I'm using ant build.xml files to build and I'm calling it from jenkins. The values I need to modify are in the property files of the checked out project...

Comment: What all properties do you need to change?

Comment: @ChandikaGunawardhana: Check my edited answer. If there are variables besides JAVA_HOME, TOMCAT_HOME etc. that you need to change in the XML, you can use EnvInject plugin. Check my updated answer (last line).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply specify the properties in the ant builder section of your jobs config (you'll need to hit the advanced button to see the properties box).

Properties in ant are immutable, so setting them when ant is called will override whatever is in your properties file.

You want to avoid a build step that changes your source controlled files.

Comment: +1 for quoting the `immutable` property. Your answer is definitely simpler. I completely missed the available `Properties` section in Ant. :(